# unplublish article showing on frontend for every one

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, articles

I am working on `joomla 3.5.1` and facing a strange issue that after unpublished the article, article is visible on front end for everyone. I cleared cache and other relevant things but no effect. Only **Unpublished** started showing. Same issue I am facing for modules too.

Comment: maybe you have to log out from the front-end as admin user

Comment: I already tried that. on different browsers

Comment: What do you mean with Only Unpublished started showing? Is this for a certain article only? Are you sure you don't have twice the same article, or you the article you are seeing in front-end is the same with the one you have unpublished? And is it unpublished or archived? What happens if you open and save again that article?

Comment: `Unpublished` is the text started to showing with the title of article when it is unpublished. other articles are showing as well. Yes, I don't have duplicate articles. My changes are reflecting in the article so I think I am working on right one.

Comment: Have your tried clearing browser cache? Also check that you don't have two versions of the article. A link would be useful too - it sounds like you may think that you unpublished, but you actually did something else.

Comment: What component/module is outputting your articles? Do you have Template overrides? Please add more details of your system settings

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Featured Article identifier before Unpublished. 
make it sure to Clear your browser cache before viewing your site again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're logged in at front-end, try to go with browser in incognito mode and check if issue appears.